# Manage more than 1000 active Team Projects in TFS2010 or TFS2012

Tags: scaling, team-project

Can TFS2010 or TFS2012 manage more than 1000 active Projects?
Now we use the QualityCenter each Project is a SQL-DB and about 100 User Access per day.

I found the TFS2010 Limits in the "Scaling Team Foundation Server 2012 Whitepaper" documentation

TFS 2010 Limits

- 200 Team Projects per Team Project Collection
- 50 – 200 Active Team Project Collections per SQL Instance (range for 8GB – 64Gb of RAM)

So it is possible to create 10 Collections, each Collections should have 100 Team Projects integrated? So what amount of RAM do i need?

If I have 200 Team Projects in a Collection it that the same when I have 200 Collections? So the amount of required RAM is the same?

Does somebody have experiences with these amout of projects

Comment: It is more off topic as this is a system administration question and should go on serverfault. It does not deal with programming and mostly stuff like scaling will be admin responsibility.

Answer (score 2):

A project collection equals to a database. So having 200 projects in one Project Collection is definitly not the same as having 200 project collections with one project. In the first case, you'll have one big database. In case of the second you'll have 200 databases.

As for scaling, the rules are pretty clear, *you can have up to 200 projects in a project collection.*

*Depending on the size and activity in each project collection, you can have between 50 and 200 project collections on a SQL Server instance* (that doesn't mean on a TFS Instance!). Especially the activity greatly influences the amount of memory needed and thus is the greatest factory for decidign the number of projectcolelctions. 200 stale collections are easy to maintain. But 75 very active ones might be the limit in your case.

*You can have any number of SQL Server instances linked to your TFS server.* After creating your Project Collection you have the ability to move it to another server for the SQL Server hosting. (See http://healthedev.blogspot.nl/2011/12/move-tfs-2010-project-collection.html).

When you're talking about these kinds of sizes in databases, make sure that the TFS Reporting is installed on it's own box(es). And that the TFS Warehouse refresh frequecies make any sense (don't do every minute updates with these amounts of data)... and make sure the TFS_Warehouse and the Analysis cube each have a SQL instance that has plenty of memory and CPU to process properly.